# Как работает функция abs() при использовании битового ~?

Tags: python, binary

Обьясните пожалуйста, как работает функция abs() при использовании битового ~. В ответе на вопрос 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573219/the-meaning-of-bit-wise-not-in-python
прочитал, что

> It is toggling all the bits. All of them, including an infinite number of leading zeros, producing an infinite number of leading ones, because Python simulates an infinite-bit representation, not 3-bit or 32-bit or 64-bit or any finite number. Python can't show you an infinite number of leading ones, so instead, it shows you bin(abs(b)) with a - sign in front. abs(b) is 6 and bin(6) is '0b110', so you see -0b110.

Что делает функция abs() в данном случае? Почему abs(b) возвращает 6, а не то значение, которое было ей передано? Заранее благодарен за пояснение.

Comment: ~5 = -6. abs(-6) = 6. Что именно вам не понятно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по вашему вопросу, да и вопросу по ссылке, имеет место недостаток знаний о битовом хранении отрицательных чисел.

Самым распространенным на данный момент способом является [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Например знаковому числу -6 соответствует такое беззнаковое число, что сумма его с числом +6 (с учетом переполнения) даст 0. Для однобайтового (8-битного) числа это будет 0b11111010. Для 32-битного — 0b11111111111111111111111111111010.

Можно проследить одну особенность: отрицательному числу соответствует представление положительного числа на единицу меньше по модулю, у которого инвертировали все биты. -x = ~ (x-1)

Эта особенность указана в [справочнике по операции ~](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators): ~x = -x - 1.

bin() в питоне учитывает знаковость числа, и вместо вереницы лидирующих единиц выводит минус, за которым битовое представление модуля числа.

0b11111111111111111111111111111010 = -6 = -1*6 = -0b110. Это просто более удобная форма записи, а не реальное представление числа в памяти. Также точно как и десятичное -6 в памяти хранится как +4294967290, но то, что оно выводится как -6 никого не смущает.

Comment: В дополнительном коде очень легко отличить положительное знаковое число от отрицательного - у отрицательного всегда старший бит установлен в 1.